# Google Maps API DirectionsRendererOptions not working?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use DirectionsRenderer to display a DirectionsResult without the route list.  According to the API version 3 documentation, there is a "hideRouteList" property of the DirectionsRendererOptions object that when set to true should hide the route list.  I cannot get it to work.  Is this a bug or am I just not coding this correctly?  Following is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Driving Directions</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function initialize() {
    var dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var dirRequest = {
          origin: "350 5th Ave, New York, NY, 10118",
          destination: "1 Wall St, New York, NY",
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
          provideTripAlternatives: true
    };
    dirService.route(dirRequest, showDirections);
}

function showDirections(dirResult, dirStatus) {
    if (dirStatus != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        alert('Directions failed: ' + dirStatus);
        return;
    }
    var rendererOptions = {
        hideRouteList: true
    };
    var dirRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);  
    dirRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById('dir-container'));
    dirRenderer.setDirections(dirResult);
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize();">
<div id="dir-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [tried this out](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo27) and I don't think you are doing anything wrong.  Looks like this option is broken.  I couldn't find it in the [known issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles), so I think this is a new one.  When I get a chance I'll write it up.

Comment: Logged an issue here -> http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2247

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the documentation, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question!

hideRouteList:true hides route options, not the route markup. This only applies in conjunction with setting provideRouteAlternatives: true on the request object, which you've also supplied.

Below is my quick test. Set hideRouteList to true/false to see the difference in the route markup below. In my case there are no route options, but it does have different markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Driving Directions example.</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        MySite.MapAdmin.init();
    });


    var MySite = {};

    MySite.MapAdmin = {
        mapOptions: {
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.51257, -84.336609)
        },
        mapRendererOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            panel: document.getElementById('map-directions'),
            hideRouteList: false
        },
        directionDisplay: null,
        directionsService: null,
        map: null,
        init: function () {

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), this.mapOptions);            
            this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(this.mapRendererOptions);           
            this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

            this.plotRoute();

        },
        plotRoute: function () {

            var selectedMode = "DRIVING"; // DRIVING, WALKING, BICYCLING

            var request = {
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(46.51257, -84.336609),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(46.61257, -84.336609),
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[selectedMode],
                provideRouteAlternatives: true
            };

            MySite.MapAdmin.directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    MySite.MapAdmin.directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('map-directions'));
                    MySite.MapAdmin.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

        }
    };


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <div id="map-directions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```